# Obtener valores de un JSON en node.js

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Estoy teniendo problemas con este código en Node.js. Necesito obtener la información que se encuentra en "Contents" del JSON pero me da un error que dice: **" e.Contents.forEach is not a function"** supongo que es un problema de lógica pero honestamente no se me ocurre nada mas, me podrían dar un ejemplo de como solucionarlo, por favor?

Este es el JSON:

```
var jsonFile = {
"Notification": [
    {
        "Channel":1, 
        "Type":1,
        "Means":
            [{
                "Number":88888888,
                "Code":506
            }]
        ,
        "Contents":{
            "Message":"This is a message"
        }   
    }
    ] 
}
```

Este es el código:

```
function Fe(jsonFile){
  jsonFile.Notification.forEach(e =>{
    e.Means.forEach(function(v){
      e.Contents.forEach(function(n){
        console.log(n.Message);
      })
})
}
```

Comment: Antes contents era un Array pero me di cuenta que no lo necesitaba de esa manera por lo menos para este ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema en tu código es que si te fijas en la indentación, `Message` y el subobjeto `Contents` no están dentro del subobjeto `Means` (que es un arreglo).
Adicionalmente ni `Contents` ni `Message` son arreglos, así que no puedes realizar un `forEach` a ellos.

```js
var jsonFile = {
"Notification": [
    {
        "Channel":1, 
        "Type":1,
        "Means":
            [{
                "Number":88888888,
                "Code":506
            }]
        ,
        "Contents":{
            "Message":"This is a message"
        }   
    }
    ] 
}

jsonFile.Notification.forEach(e =>{
    console.log(e.Contents);
    console.log(e.Contents.Message);
})
```

Guíate siempre en la indentación para saber como acceder a los objetos, en este caso ayuda si lo representas como árbol

```
                 Notification
              /      |       \        \
            /        |        \          \
          /          |         \             \ 
   Channel         Type        Means        Contents
   /                |         /     \               |
 1                  1      Number   Code          Message
                           |         |                 |
                      88888888      506         "This is a message"
```

Comment: Lo adapte y funciona perfectamente! Gracias!!

Comment: Genial! te agregué un pequeño diagramita de los objetos, en cada vértice le pones un punto para acceder al siguiente, ej. `Notification.Means.Code` espero te ayude a comprender mejor como funcionan los objetos en JS

Comment: Wow! Muchisimas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

No olvides antes hacer las validaciones para conocer si existe las propiedades de tu objeto

```js
var jsonFile = {
"Notification": [
    {
        "Channel":1, 
        "Type":1,
        "Means":
            [{
                "Number":88888888,
                "Code":506
            }]
        ,
        "Contents":{
            "Message":"This is a message"
        }   
    }
    ] 
};

var notas=jsonFile["Notification"][0]["Contents"];
console.log(JSON.stringify(notas));
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Haciendo uso del destructuring te ahorras unas cuantas líneas.

```
const Fe = ( jsonFile ) =>
   jsonFile.Notification.forEach(({ Contents: { Message } }) =>
     console.log(Message);
   );
```